# Some questions on the proof of Hahn-Banach Theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

**Theorem**:    Let $q:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a sublinear functional on a real linear space $X$. Let $M$ be a linear subspace of $X$ and suppose that $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a linear functional such that $f(x)\leqslant q(x)$ for all $x\in M$. Then there exists a linear functional $F:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $F(x)\leqslant q(x)$ for all $x\in X$ and $F(x)=f(x)$ for all $x\in M$.

I am trying to write the proof as my homework but I meet some questions. Basically, I followed the proof on here: https://www.impan.pl/~lpalmisano/fa2017/lecture6.pdf. But I have two questions about the details in the proof.

1. In the first part of the proof, let $S$ be the collection of all pairs $(M_1,f_1)$, where $M_1$ is a linear subspace of $X$ such that $M\subseteq M_1$ and $f_1$ is a linear extension of $f$ with $f_1(x)\leqslant q(x)$ for all $x\in M_1$. Then how to get $S\neq\emptyset$? Is it because $(M,f)\in S$?
2. In the second part of the proof, we fix $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and define define $F:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $F(tx_0+y)=t\alpha+f(y)$ ($t\in\mathbb{R},y\in M$). How to show $F$ is well defined? And my attempt is: If $y_1=y_2\in M$ and $t_1=t_2\in\mathbb{R}$, then $$F(t_1x_0+y_1)=t_1\alpha+f(y_1)=t_2\alpha+f(y_2)=F(t_2x_0+y_2).$$ Thus $F:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is well defined. 
   But my professor mentioned this part was wrong.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: For your first question, you can take $M_1:=M+\mathbb{R}x_0$ for some $x_0\notin M$, and define $f_1:M_1\to\mathbb{R}$ via $f_1(x+rx_0)=f(x)+ry_0$ where $y_0$ is any fixed number satisfying $$\sup_{y\in M}(f(y)-q(y-x))\leq y_0\leq \inf_{y\in M}(q(y+x)-f(y)).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Note that you are not defining $F$ on $X$, but on $\mathbb R x_0+M$. If you assume that $y_1=y_2$ and $t_1=t_2$, then there is nothing to prove. What you have to do is to assume that $t_1x_0+y_1=t_2x_0+y_2$. This you can rewrite as 
   $$
   (t_1-t_2)x_0=y_2-y_1. 
   $$
   Since $x_0\not\in M$ (that's the point, to extend from $M$, so $x_0\not\in M$) you get $t_1-t_2=0$. And then you get $y_2-y_1=0$. That is, there is a single $t$ and a single $y$ to express $tx_0+y\in \mathbb R x_0+M$. Thus $F$ is well-defined.

Comment: @MartinArgeramithere Thanks for your relpy. But I am sorry I don't understand why there is a single $t$ and a single $y$ to express $tx_0+y\in \mathbb R x_0+M$ makes $F$ well defined.

Comment: Because that's precisely the information you use to define $F$: $t$ and $y$. If you had $w=2x_0+y=3x_0+z$, with $y,z\in M$, what would  $F(w)$ be?

Comment: @MartinArgeramiLet Ok, do you think it is ok I show well defined in this way. Let $y_1,y_2\in M$ and $t_1,t_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $t_1x_0+y_1=t_2x_0+y_2$. Then $(t_1-t_2)x_0=y_2-y_1$. Since $x_0\in X-M$ and $y_2-y_1\in M$, $t_1=t_2$ and $y_1=y_2$. Thus $$F(t_1x_0+y_1)=t_1\alpha+f(y_1)=t_2\alpha+f(y_2)=F(t_2x_0+y_2).$$ Hence, $F:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is well defined.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.